# Django - Append Path to get_absolute_url

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

Is it possible to append path to `get_absolute_url`? For instance, I want to append `/credentials/` to the following code so the final output would be something like  `/api/v2/job_templates/9/credentials/",`

```
    if obj.unified_job_template:
        res['unified_job_template'] = obj.unified_job_template.get_absolute_url(self.context.get('request'))
```

This is what it looks like at the moment..

[image]

Here is the full code:

```
def get_url(self, obj):
    if obj is None or not hasattr(obj, 'get_absolute_url'):
        return ''
    elif isinstance(obj, User):
        return self.reverse('api:user_detail', kwargs={'pk': obj.pk})
    else:
        return obj.get_absolute_url(request=self.context.get('request'))

def get_absolute_url(self, request=None):
    return reverse('api:unified_job_template', kwargs={'pk': self.pk}, request=request)



class WorkflowJobTemplateNodeSerializer(LaunchConfigurationBaseSerializer):
    success_nodes = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(many=True, read_only=True)
    failure_nodes = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(many=True, read_only=True)
    always_nodes = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(many=True, read_only=True)
    exclude_errors = ('required',)  # required variables may be provided by WFJT or on launch

    credentials = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(
        many=True, queryset=Credential.objects.all(),
        required=False, write_only=True
    )    

    class Meta:
        model = WorkflowJobTemplateNode
        fields = ('*', 'workflow_job_template', '-name', '-description', 'id', 'url', 'related',
                  'unified_job_template', 'success_nodes', 'failure_nodes', 'credentials', 'always_nodes', 'all_parents_must_converge',
                  'identifier')

    def get_related(self, obj):
        res = super(WorkflowJobTemplateNodeSerializer, self).get_related(obj)
        res['create_approval_template'] = self.reverse('api:workflow_job_template_node_create_approval', kwargs={'pk': obj.pk})
        res['success_nodes'] = self.reverse('api:workflow_job_template_node_success_nodes_list', kwargs={'pk': obj.pk})
        res['failure_nodes'] = self.reverse('api:workflow_job_template_node_failure_nodes_list', kwargs={'pk': obj.pk})
        res['always_nodes'] = self.reverse('api:workflow_job_template_node_always_nodes_list', kwargs={'pk': obj.pk})        

        if obj.unified_job_template:
            res['unified_job_template'] = obj.unified_job_template.get_absolute_url(self.context.get('request'))
        try:
            res['workflow_job_template'] = self.reverse('api:workflow_job_template_detail', kwargs={'pk': obj.workflow_job_template.pk})
        except WorkflowJobTemplate.DoesNotExist:
            pass
        return res

    def build_relational_field(self, field_name, relation_info):
        field_class, field_kwargs = super(WorkflowJobTemplateNodeSerializer, self).build_relational_field(field_name, relation_info)
        # workflow_job_template is read-only unless creating a new node.
        if self.instance and field_name == 'workflow_job_template':
            field_kwargs['read_only'] = True
            field_kwargs.pop('queryset', None)
        return field_class, field_kwargs

    def get_summary_fields(self, obj):
        summary_fields = super(WorkflowJobTemplateNodeSerializer, self).get_summary_fields(obj)

        if isinstance(obj.unified_job_template, WorkflowApprovalTemplate):
            summary_fields['unified_job_template']['timeout'] = obj.unified_job_template.timeout
        return summary_fields
```

Answer (score -1):

create one variable called full_url

**full_url = unified_job_template + "credentials/"**
and then

return reverse('**api:full_url**', kwargs={'pk': self.pk}, request=request)

this should work

Comment: I get tehf ollowing error.. `NameError: name 'unified_job_template ' is not defined`